# Adding product thumbnail on new order transactional email?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, transactional-mail

I would like to add `<img src="{{var product_image}} “ border="0" />` to the "new order" email template but I didn't see a clear place to insert it. I'm using CE 1.9.1.0

I see the product info is contained within `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` which points to **sales.xml** and from there I see the template used is **email/order/items.phtml** but even then I notice the template doesn't match whats sent when I place a new order.

I know the template used is **app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html** but I don't understand how I can insert the image thumbnail when all the product data is contained within the layout handle above. Any guidance would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` this syntax point to file

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml
```

In this file you will need to add one more column for thumbnail image.

File code should be like

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Image') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th align="right" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
    <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <tbody>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php if ($this->helper('giftmessage/message')->isMessagesAvailable('order', $_order, $_order->getStore()) && $_order->getGiftMessageId()): ?>
    <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
    <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
<br />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Gift Message for this Order') ?></strong></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="left" style="padding:3px 9px">
            <strong><?php echo $this->__('From:'); ?></strong> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
            <br /><strong><?php echo $this->__('To:'); ?></strong> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
            <br /><strong><?php echo $this->__('Message:'); ?></strong><br /> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Above code will add one more column in your order item, now for displaying image in every product row you will need to change in file

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml
```

In this file code should be like

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());
?> 
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
    </td>

    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $this->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) :?>
            <?php echo $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered()*1 ?></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceExclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getRowTotal()) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <br />
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore()) || $this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesBothPrices($_order->getStore())): ?>
                <br /><span class="label"><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?>:</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getSubtotalInclTax($_item); ?>
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl-$_item->getWeeeTaxRowDisposition()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item)): ?>
                <br />
                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 1, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><small><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></small></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php elseif (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 4, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <small>
                    <?php foreach (Mage::helper('weee')->getApplied($_item) as $tax): ?>
                        <span class="nobr"><?php echo $tax['title']; ?>: <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($tax['row_amount_incl_tax'],true,true); ?></span><br />
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </small>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, 2, 'email', $_order->getStore())): ?>
                    <span class="nobr"><?php echo Mage::helper('weee')->__('Total incl. tax'); ?>:<br /> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_incl + Mage::helper('weee')->getRowWeeeTaxInclTax($_item)); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if ($_item->getGiftMessageId() && $_giftMessage = $this->helper('giftmessage/message')->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style=" border-bottom:2px solid #CCCCCC; padding:3px 9px;">
        <strong style="color:#444444; font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->__('Gift Message') ?></strong>
        <?php echo $this->__('From:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?><br />
        <?php echo $this->__('To:'); ?> <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?><br />
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Message:'); ?></strong><br /><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**You will need to take this both the file from base to your theme template folder with correct folder structure.**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, will try this in a moment.

Comment: Works as expected, only issue is the thumbnail is very large. I had to use `width` / `height` attributes to resize it.